# replacing the special character which is showing as encoded

Tags: java, coldfusion, cfml, lucee, canonicalization

using canonicalize function to convert a value into a actual single quote:

```
&#39
```

but when I dump the code, it seems good, in db, it is stored as single quote, when loaded in text box, it becomes that character

problem seems to the hash which is popping up and unable to do to decode, is there any other way i can do. this is really messing up

Comment: Please try this function HTMLCodeFormat()

Comment: Consider `HTMLCodeFormat()` is deprecated as the `encodeFor*` functions handle vastly more characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for `EncodeForHTML()`

```
<cfsavecontent variable="data">&#39</cfsavecontent>

<cfset data = canonicalize(data, true, true)>

<cfoutput>
<textarea>#EncodeForHTML(data)#</textarea>
</cfoutput>
```

It is likely that your entity was not quite correct. Here it is with a ;

```
<cfsavecontent variable="data">&#39;</cfsavecontent>

<cfset data = canonicalize(data, true, true)>

<cfoutput>
<textarea>#EncodeForHTML(data)#</textarea>
</cfoutput>
```

See ColdFusion Fiddle: https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=36318397-176d-4b4e-b741-b9f1d2ebc290/1883347c-5e31-4d9c-a759-68938935d066/360cdb86-71f4-47b4-ad90-c19f40b444b6.cfm